# Get list of index where their values are null in PHP

Tags: php

I have an array like

```
["21261","21262",null , null , "5000" , null , "5555"]
```

I need to get a list of indexes where their values are null in PHP, like

```
[2,3,5]
```

Thanks

Comment: "I need" is not really a question and does not adhere to the site rules. Please edit to show your best effort and try to explain where and how it fails, then we can help you identify the problem.

Comment: Try it with `foreach ($array as $key => $value)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `array_filter` for specific condittion for array filter elements

```php
$ar=["21261","21262",null , null , "5000" , null , "5555"];

$null=array_filter($ar,function($a){
     return $a==null;
    });

print_r(array_keys($null)); //[2,3,5]
```

[run](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f66263c81a34fc2036514655b3cac3212c783cd9)

Comment: You're not really helping the OP this way IMHO, and if you do want to add feedback to the discussion(there isn't an actual question), you might want to explain your code a bit, so it helps future researchers

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// Your array
$a = ['test', null, 'hi', null];

// Empty array to push the keys
$a_null = [];

foreach($a as $key => $ele) {
    
    // check if null
    if($ele === null) {
        // push the key
        $a_null[] = $key;
    }
}

// output keys
var_dump($a_null);
```

This should be the easiest to way to understand it without using the inbuild php functions.